# Existence of a solution to the poisson equation with a Radon measure on the right hand side.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was trying to guarantee the existence of a solution to the problem

$$-\Delta u=\mu,\quad u\lvert_{\partial\Omega}=0$$

where $\mu$ is a signed Radon measure, i.e., $\mu(A)=\int_{A}f\,dx$, $f\in L^1(\Omega)$. I defined a functional

$$I(u)=\int_{\Omega}(1/2)|\nabla u|^2\,dx - \int_{\Omega}uf\,dx.$$

The first term is in $C^1$ (easy to see) but the second term $\int_{\Omega}ufdx$ where $f\in L^1$ has its derivative equal to $\int_{\Omega}vfdx$ for $v\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Now my question is whether $\int_{\Omega}vfdx$  is continuous over $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$?.

Comment: Somebody would like to close your question, since you do not provide any motivation for your problem and you did not show your efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the criticism friends. I was trying to guarantee an existence of a solution to the problem $-\Delta u=\mu, u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ where $\mu$ is a signed Radon measure, i.e., $\mu(A)=\int_{A}fdx$, $f\in L^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: I defined a functional $I(u)=\int_{\Omega}(1/2)|\nabla u|^2-\int_{\Omega}ufdx$. The first term is in $C^1$ (easy to see) but the second term $\int_{\Omega}ufdx$ where $f\in L^1$ has its derivative equal to $\int_{\Omega}vfdx$ for $v\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Now my question is whether $\int_{\Omega}vfdx$  is continuous over $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$?.

Comment: What is a solution for you in this context?

Comment: @Tomas...the solution is in thexweak sense...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f \in L^1$. The functional $v \mapsto \int_\Omega vf dx$ is continuous (i.e. bounded) on $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ if $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$, which is the case if $p > n$, the spatial dimension of $\Omega$.

In that case actually $W^{1,p} \subset C(\Omega)$ (with compact embedding), so the functional is bounded even if you have a general Radon measure $\mu$ and the functional $v \mapsto \int_\Omega v d \mu$.

If $p < n$, the functional is not bounded. General example: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$  be the unit ball. Set $v(x) = |x|^{-\alpha}$ with $p(\alpha+1) < n$ (which is possible since $p < n$) and $f(x) = |x|^{\alpha - n}$. Then $v \in W^{1,p}$ and $f \in L^1$, but $v(x)f(x) = |x|^{-n}$ which is not integrable.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I was especially interested in the case when $p<n$.

Comment: See my edited answer.